# How can I get exact value string of huge numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bignum

I know JavaScript numbers are just "double" numbers and have only 52bit precisions for the fraction part. However, the REAL JavaScript numbers seem to have more practical precisions for huge numbers.

For example, the predefined constant `Number.MAX_VALUE` represents the largest positive finite value of the Number type, which is approximately 1.7976931348623157e+308. Here I can access trailing digits of this value using a modulus operator.

```
> Number.MAX_VALUE
1.7976931348623157e+308
> Number.MAX_VALUE % 10000000000
4124858368
```

From this result I can assume that this number is `7fef ffff ffff ffff` which represents (1 + (1 − 2 ** −52)) × 2 ** 1023 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples)) and can be transcribed in an exact form as following:

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

...and we only saw trailing 10 digits of this 309 digits. So I think each JavaScript number must have **exact** digits in the decimal form.

My question is: how to get this 309 digits string in JavaScript? Challenges like `Number.MAX_VALUE / 10000000000 % 10000000000` just fails because of such hugeness.

Furthermore, how about tiny numbers such as `Number.MIN_VALUE`? This must be the following fraction in the decimal form.

```
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004940656458412465441765687928682213723650598026143247644255856825006755072702087518652998363616359923797965646954457177309266567103559397963987747960107818781263007131903114045278458171678489821036887186360569987307230500063874091535649843873124733972731696151400317153853980741262385655911710266585566867681870395603106249319452715914924553293054565444011274801297099995419319894090804165633245247571478690147267801593552386115501348035264934720193790268107107491703332226844753335720832431936092382893458368060106011506169809753078342277318329247904982524730776375927247874656084778203734469699533647017972677717585125660551199131504891101451037862738167250955837389733598993664809941164205702637090279242767544565229087538682506419718265533447265625
```

Comment: Your assumptions are not correct. JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating point numbers, and that is that.

Comment: Try this in your JavaScript console: `(1e25+1) === 1e25`

Answer (score 0):

All digits of MAX_VALUE is:
`179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Check out the code below:

http://howjs.com/?%3Aload%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.javascriptoo.com%2Fapplication%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2FMikeMcl%2Fbig.js%2Fbig.min.js%0A%0Avar%20max%20%3D%20new%20Big(%20Number.MAX_VALUE%20)%3B%0Amax.toFixed()%3B

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation of IEEE floating point numbers is a little (little!!!) confusing.

I find it helps if you think of a simpler form, this reacts the same everywhere except near the overflows and underflows where the IEEE format is just better.

This is the form:

A floating point number consists of:

1. A sign for the number (+/-)
2. An unsigned integer value called the "mantissa" -- make this 'v'
3. An unsigned integer value called the "exponent" -- make this 'n'
4. A "sign" for the exponent.

The sign of the number is simple -- does it have a minus in front. 
The value is calculated as:

```
v*2ⁿ
```

If the sign for the exponent is positive the exponent is basically 2*2*2*...*2 for as many twos as you have specified. If a large number is represented in decimal it will have lots of digits all the way down to the decimal point BUT they are meaningless. If you display the number in binary after about 53 binary digits all the rest will be zeros and you can't change them.

Notice, with a positive exponent all this is integers, floating point numbers (including IEEE ones) will calculate exactly with integers as long as you don't overflow. When you overflow they are still well behaved, they just have zeros in the lower bits.

Only when the exponent is negative do you have strangeness

```
v/(2ⁿ)
```

The value you get for a negative exponent is still based on the 2*2*2*...*2 value but you divide by it instead. So you're trying to represent say a tenth with a sum of halves, quarters, eighths and so forth ... but this doesn't work exactly so you get rounding errors and all the lovely floating point problems.

Your example value:

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

In binary it is

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

There's lots of zeros on the end.

[What every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)